# What is the memory cost of a CNN?

Tags: cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I was recently thinking about the memory cost of (a) training a CNN and (b) inference with a CNN. Please note, that I am not talking about the storage (which is simply the number of parameters).

How much memory does a given CNN (e.g. VGG-16 D) need for

- (a) Training (with ADAM)
- (b) Inference on a single image?

### My thoughts

Basically, I want to make sure that I didn't forget anything with this question. If you have other sources which explain this kind of thought, please share them with me.

#### (a) Training

For training with ADAM, I will now assume that I have a Mini-batch size of $B \in \mathbb{N}$ and $w \in \mathbb{N}$ is the number of parameters of the CNN. Then the memory footprint (the maximum amount of memory I need at any point while training) for a single training pass is:

- $2w$: Keep the weights and the weight updates in memory
- $B \cdot $ Size of all generated feature maps (forward pass)
- $w$: Gradients for each weight (backpropagation)
- $w$: Learning rates for each weight (ADAM)

#### (b) Inference

In inference, it is not necessary to store a feature map of layer $i-1$ if the feature maps of layer $i$ are already calculated. So the memory footprint while inference is:

- $w$: The model
- The two most expensive successive layers (one which is already calculated, the net one which gets calculated)

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but this post also attempt to consider complexity of a NN: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/computational-complexity-of-neural-network-language-model

Comment: Here is a good article for you:
[Why is so much memory needed for deep neural networks?](https://www.graphcore.ai/blog/why-is-so-much-memory-needed-for-deep-neural-networks) Hope it helps

Comment: Related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/65481/27916

Comment: @MartinThoma, during inference, is ur proposed memory requirement is correct? Do we only need memory equivalent to model + two most expensive successive layers?

Answer (score 2):

**Total RAM would be -** Batch size X RAM to train one image (since backpropagation happens after the batch)

**RAM for one training image -**

**A/** 4 Bytes X Number of parm

**B/** Size of input for each layer considering downsampling and number of features map

(Suppose input are 200 × 300 pixels, the first layer’s feature maps might be 100 × 150, the second layer’s feature maps can be 50 × 75, and the third layer’s feature maps can be 25 × 38. The first convolutional layer has 100 feature maps, this first layer takes up 4 × 100 × 150 × 100 = 6 million bytes (6 MB). The second layer will take up 4 × 50 × 75 × 200 = 3 million bytes (3 MB).

**C/** Size for the input image